# Firebase Storage in Emulator: refFromUrl() expected a valid full URL

Tags: typescript, firebase-storage, firebase-tools

Is it possible `refFromURL()` is not working in local?

```js
  function deleteImage(imageUrl: string) {
    let urlRef = firebase.storage().refFromURL(imageUrl)
    return urlRef.delete().catch((error) => console.error(error))
  }
```

When passing the following url:

`http://localhost:9199/v0/b/xxx.appspot.com/o/images%2Fdemo%2FHWEGgAPDSZrtMzbil2MwM.image%2Fjpeg?alt=media&token=a7f798ee-056a-4f03-a7bf-8453b71077e6`

I get the following error:

`Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: refFromUrl() expected a valid full URL but got an invalid one. (storage/invalid-argument)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future googlers, this is a [known issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3715) that was [fixed](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/pull/5453) in [Firebase SDK 9.0.2](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_902_-_september_9_2021). See the issue for details, but as far as I can tell, the problem had to do with the URL parser not liking `http` links. Normally this is fine, but the local emulator runs on localhost, and localhost will be `http` for the foreseeable future.

```bash
$ npm i firebase@9.0.2

# or

$ npm i firebase@latest
```

Note: If you're coming from version 8.x.x or lower, there *are* some breaking changes. Lucky for us, there is a "compat" API that should keep your immediate code changes minimal. Here's a [migration guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) for you.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem, and wasn't able to find a proper solution.

I ended up getting around it by implementing a check in my app to see if the url contains "localhost:9199", if it does then it should just be provided as is. If it doesn't, that means the code is being used in a production environment and needs to be unpacked using refFromUrl().

This is just a workaround rather than a proper fix. Hopefully someone else out there will help us out!

```
export default async function getPostInfo(id) {
  const ref = firestore.collection("posts").doc(id);
  const doc = await ref.get();
  const imgRef = doc.data().image;
  // To handle firebase storage emulator. .refFromURL() doesn't work with locally stored files in the emulator.
  let image;
  const regex = new RegExp(/localhost:9199/);
  if (!regex.test(imgRef)) {
    image = await storage.refFromURL(imgRef).getDownloadURL();
  } else {
    image = doc.data().image;
  }

  return { ...doc.data(), image, id: doc.id };
}
```